# Is there a way to control the Alpha of the Freestyle lines by Sun Direction?

Tags: freestyle

I'm trying to get the lines to emphasize the light direction, but can't seem to control the Alpha in anyway to do that... or fake it.

Comment: Hello :). It is possible to fake it by using the *Distance modifier* in the *Freestyle Line Style*. I can post a full answer if you're interested.

Comment: I have been trying to the "Distance from Camera," which adds a similar affect but still adds lines in areas not affected by the light and does not match the direction.  I have not tried distance from object tho.  Would you suggest placing an object that fakes the light location and use that?

Comment: Freestyle lines cannot be affected by your actual lightsource, because they are added *on top* of the render.

Answer (score 2):

**You can fake it with the Distance from Object modifier.**
The distance from specified object will then control the transparency.

**How to:**
1) In your *Freestyle Line Style* go to the *Alpha* tab and add the *Distance from Object* modifier.
2) Set the Blend mode to Subtract
3) Set your *Target* object. (from which the distance will be measured)
4) Set *Min/Max Range* for best result. (or use the *Fill range by selection* button)
5) Done.

*Line Style* setings
[image]

*Result*
[image]

Comment: Great!  Thank you!  I will give it a try.